# Webpack: join svg files to symbol and generate css (sass) stylesheet for each entry

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, sass, symbols

Question is in the title.
My webpack config: https://github.com/skutin/webpack4-simple-boilerplate

I'm trying to create a icon system with svg and symbol.
What I would like to see as a result:

Input:
`/src/icons/*.svg`

Output:

1. `/dist/symbols.svg` - all icons in one file
2. `/dist/css/icons.css` with content like this:

```
.icon-favorite {
    background-image: url(/dist/symbols.svg#favorite);
}

.icon-forward {
    background-image: url(/dist/symbols.svg#forward);
}
```

I figured out the first thing with https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader

But I stucked with generating css based on files list.

Any ideas please?

Update: I am migrating from gulp, so this is my current code, it shows my expected result: https://gist.github.com/skutin/fa14e0a04713a065efcfa8fdc0af3db5

Comment: Why don't you put the styles you need inside of the .svg document?

Comment: @enxaneta I hope there is a more automatic solution. Actually, I am migrating from gulp, so this is my current code, it shows my expected result: https://gist.github.com/skutin/fa14e0a04713a065efcfa8fdc0af3db5